# Tensorflow modelling

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have started some exploration into tensorflow and it's modelling capabilities.

I have a number of normalised 400x500 images stored as numpy arrays.

These are organised as:
180 for training category A,
20 for testing category A,
50 for training category B, and
11 for testing category.

For the moment I am using the introductory model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(400, 500)),
    keras.layers.Dense(12, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(8, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size = 5)
```

train_images contains [0-199] category A and [200-249] category B images.
train_labels contains the respective labels.

During execution, accuracy always sits at around 0.78, irrespective of the number of epochs used. Loss also does not change.

0.78 seems to be close to the ratio of imaged between category A and B.

I would appreciate any assistance to help get going.

Thank you.

Comment: You should look at false/true negative score it will tell you if you learned something.

Comment: you can also use weight on labels that are not balanced

Answer (score 0):

I think your model is too simple. You have three dense layers with just a few neurons, that does not seem like something that would be able to recognize some complex features in input of size 200000. You should try first a few convolutional layers.